# MMCFE Not Reporting Stats from pushpool/wallet

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin

I spent the last two days setting up a Litecoin Mining Pool and from what I can tell, absolutely everything is setup and working correctly. However, after creating a new worker and connecting to it, I have noticed that the stats on the website never update.

I have included my pushpool configuration below, but I am at a loss as to where the issue might be?

```
[root@test sbin]# vi server.json
{
        # network ports
        "listen" : [
                # binary protocol (default), port 8336
                { "port" : 8336 },

                # HTTP JSON-RPC protocol, port 8337
                { "port" : 8337, "protocol" : "http-json" },

                # HTTP JSON-RPC protocol, port 8339,
                # with trusted proxy appserver.example.com forwarding
                # requests to us
                #{ "port" : 8339, "protocol" : "http-json",
                #  "proxy" : "appserver.example.com" },

                # binary protocol, localhost-only port 8338
                { "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : 8338, "protocol" : "binary" }
        ],

        # database settings
        "database" : {
                "engine" : "mysql",

                # 'host' defaults to localhost, if not specified
                "host" : "localhost",

                # 'port' uses proper default port for the DB engine,
                # if not specified
                "port" : 3306,

                "name" : "mmcfe",
                "username" : "user",
                "password" : "pass",

                "stmt.pwdb" :
                  "SELECT password FROM pool_worker WHERE username = ?"
        },

        # cache settings
        #"memcached" : {
        #       "servers" : [
        #               { "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : 11211 }
        #       ]
        #},

        "pid" : "/tmp/pushpoold.pid",

        # overrides local hostname detection
        #"forcehost" : "localhost.localdomain",

        "log.requests" : "/tmp/request.log",
        "log.shares" : "/tmp/shares.log",

        # the server assumes longpolling (w/ SIGUSR1 called for each blk)
        "longpoll.disable" : false,

        # length of time to cache username/password credentials, in seconds
        "auth.cred_cache.expire" : 75,

        # RPC settings
        "rpc.url" : "http://127.0.0.1:9332/",
        "rpc.user" : "user",
        "rpc.pass" : "pass",

        # rewrite returned 'target' to difficulty-1?
        "rpc.target.rewrite" : true,

        # allow clients to update the ntime field of their work
        "roll.ntime.disable" : false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add after stmt.pwd this line

```
"stmt.sharelog" :"INSERT INTO shares (rem_host, username, our_result, upstream_result, reason, solution) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

and it should do the trick ;)

for litecoin you should remove the rewrite  into
`"rpc.target.bits" : 18`,