# What is the most recent pushpool version and where to get it?

Tags: litecoin, pushpool

I found already the following pushpool versions:

```
https://github.com/jgarzik/pushpool
https://github.com/ArtForz/pushpool
https://github.com/alexhz/pushpool
https://github.com/CryptoManiac/pushpool
```

(can't post more than 2 links with my current reputation, so made a block)

All of them seem very old already.

I made a research on how to modify the difficulty in pushpool's `server.json` and found examples on how to set the following options `rpc.target.bits` and `work.expire`, but NONE of them seem to work for the mentioned versions.

So what's the newest pushpool version and where can I download it?

**EDIT:** Tried as described in the following post, but not working. Difficulty doesn't change and nothing is written into `shares`. [MMCFE Not Reporting Stats from pushpool/wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9171/mmcfe-not-reporting-stats-from-pushpool-wallet)

Comment: Did you try [this one](https://github.com/jgarzik/pushpool/tree/v0.5.1)?

Comment: Oh yes I did. Forgot to mention it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with litecoin, I believe that you are looking to serve a litecoin pool. For my needs https://github.com/ArtForz/pushpool
did the trick. It added scrypt support and allows you to rewrite the target difficulty (just remove `"rpc.target.rewrite": true` and replace it with `"rpc.target.bits": 18` in the config).

Answer (score 0):

you also need to add "sharelog" : true, otherwise it will not record your shares.

```
            "sharelog" : true,
            "stmt.pwdb":"SELECT `password` FROM `btcWorkers`.`pool_worker` WHERE username = ?",
            "stmt.sharelog":"INSERT INTO shares (rem_host, username, our_result, upstream_result, reason, solution) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```